# Shortening code

Tags: php, regex, oop, loading, delay

Nah, looks like it was hosting fault.

Who can make this code shorter?

```
private function replaceFunc($subject)
    {
        foreach($this->func as $t)
        {
            preg_match_all('/\{'.$t.'\([a-zA-Z,\']+\)\}/i', $subject, $res);
            for($j = 0; $j < sizeof($res[0]); $j++)
            {
                preg_match('/\([a-zA-Z,\']+\)/i', $res[0][$j], $match);
                if($match > 0)
                {
                    $prep = explode(", ", substr($match[0], 1, -1));
                    $args = array();
                    for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($prep); $i++)
                    {
                        $args[] = substr($prep[$i], 1, -1);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    $args = array();
                }
                $subject = preg_replace('/\{'.$t.preg_quote($match[0]).'\}/i', call_user_func_array($t, $args), $subject);
            }
        }
        return $subject;
    }
```

Comment: Jesus Christ!, wait, why do you have your functions on an array?

Comment: It is not clear what the HTML has to do with the PHP code. There does not seem to be any clear link between the two. By the way, I went to the page you linked to, and I did not notice a 10 second delay. It took less than 1 second to load.

Comment: Why are you inserting variables this way? This has got to be the worst way to insert variables from PHP into HTML ever. Good luck getting anyone to help you with this...

Comment: I gave only piece of code, but this HTML is loaded as text, then PHP finds and replace (assigned before) values, and displays it.

Comment: Have you considered using an existing templating engine, such as Smarty? http://www.smarty.net/

Comment: Here's a hint: your function will only find and replace functions that receive parameters, because your regular expression requires something to be between the (parenthesis).

Comment: @Tom - Oh, I didn't noticed that, thanks! @Jeff - Yup, however I really think that Smarty is too big for me. And I like to do something on my own ;)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/)? It already does what you need and more.

Comment: Yup, I've tried. However I really like to build things on my own (at least 90% ;D). Maybe best solution will be return to smarty.

Comment: If something is already built for you, why waste your time re-inventing the wheel when you could be getting on with solving a real problem?

Comment: In the case of Smarty, it actually does what you want it to do. It already does that 90% and you can always change the 10% with custom plugins.

Answer (score 0):

If your in the market for a templating engine, [Twig](http://www.twig-project.org/), a new templating engine used by [symfony](http://www.symfony-project.org/), is much better than smarty IMHO. If your interested in doing more than just simple HTML + foreach loop (it can do that too), Twig has features such as template inheritance, macros, and low performance overhead.